# How to log what RPC service is doing?

Tags: windows-10, rpc

My Windows 10 sometimes hangs. It starts from Firefox, but explorer, and other application is hanging at the same time too. This hang has different duration, from 1 to 60 seconds.

I noticed at this time svchost.exe process CPU usage jumps to full CPU core. Inside this process 2 services are running: Remote Procedure Call, and RPC Endpoint Mapper.

Is there a way to log what happens inside RPC service? Or is there another way how to investigate this problem? I just want to find what application causes this.